# To find basis of subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V be subspace of $M_2 (R) $ consisting of all matrices with trace o and such that entries of first row add upto zero.To find basis for this

My attempt i have posted here .according to me the dimension of subspace is 3 , one vectorfor b , 1 vector for a , and 1 vectorfor -a and -a .but they have writen in textbook dimension 3 .Can anyoneexplain . Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{pmatrix} a & -a \\b & -a\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Can you see the basis from this?

Comment: Yes thank you for answer